# Centering things. Div / img always vertical and horizontal center over cover size background?

Tags: jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/ChilledMonkeyBrain/x0jocsec/1/

^jsfiddle link^ I'm using a small jq script which gets the view port dimensions and re-scales the background image to fit. 
The problem I'm having is a div (.png) which I want to be vertically and horizontally centered on the background regardless of view port dimensions.
The current style makes it too high on mobile portrait and too low on mobile landscape. Tried lots of different units and values. 
Is there a 'one style fits all' solution, or do I need to keep re adjusting things with media queries?

Thank you!

```
<div class="hero"> 
<img class="logo" id="biglogo" src="http://www.seomofo.com/downloads/new-google-logo-knockoff.png">

       </div> 

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).bind('resizeEnd', function () {
    $(".hero").height($(window).height());
  });

  $(window).resize(function () {
    if (this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
    this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function () {
      $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
    }, 300);
  }).trigger("resize");
});
/////
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
    document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});

.hero
{   
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url(https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1419064642531-e575728395f2?q=75&fm=jpg&s=490dffe2e11f468947891ab40651e176) ;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#biglogo {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 50%;     
    margin: 25% 25%;  /*??*/
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm. It has been a while since I did this kind of thing but with fixed elements I think you need something like this in the last part of above code.

```
width: 50%; /*??*/
height: 25%;
margin-top: 50%;
top: -25%;
margin-left: 50%;
left: -25%;
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0jocsec/2/)

**Edit:** Per comment here is a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0jocsec/3/) with a wrapper class to help you position the image.

Comment: .png doesn't have to be fixed...Anything that get's the result without breaking something else will be fine. It does need a z-index, so that cuts the position options down a bit.

Comment: Changed fiddle per comment. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve this is to use `transform`, it's rather well supported today ([Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d))

```
#biglogo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3pwpny33/1/